# GQL scheme to accept multiple data structure for same key

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, gql, gqlquery

I'm currently using `GQL Modules` in my app.

In the below data structure, `content` will have either `object` or `array`

```
var A = {
  content: {
    text: "Hello"
  }
}

var B = {
  content: {
    banner: [{
      text: "Hello"
    }]
  }
}
```

How do I make `content` to accept dynamic schema ?

Below is what I tired, but not working. Please help

```
type body {
 content: TextContent | [Banner]
}

type Banner {
  text: TextContent
}

type TextContent {
 text: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL requires that a field always resolves to either a single value or a list -- it cannot resolve to either. A field *can* however, return different types altogether at runtime using an abstract type (either a union or an interface). So you can restructure your schema like this:

```
type Body {
  content: Content
}

union Content = TextContent | BannerContent

type TextContent {
  text: String
}

type BannerContent {
  banners: [Banner]
}
```

You would then query `content` using fragments:

```
query {
  someField {
    body {
      content: {
        ...on TextContent {
          text
        }
        ...on BannerContent {
          banners
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```